# Действие при потери фокуса с элемента

Tags: c#

Нашел на просторах интернета событие для элемента Control.LostFocus
Но в студии почему-то нет такого события?

Comment: WinForms/WPF/WebForms?

Answer (score 1):

Само событие есть, но оно не отображается в окне свойств,  
[`[BrowsableAttribute(false)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), посмотри здесь этот атрибут используется для [Control.LostFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx). Если тебе нужно использовать именно его, то создай свой обработчик:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // do your stuff
}
```

Привязка обработчика:

```
textBox1.LostFocus += new EventHandler(textBox1_LostFocus);
```

Если что, похожий вопрос был здесь [англоязычный stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941562/issue-with-lostfocus-event-of-a-textbox).